# Vector bundles of K(1,G) and representation of G

Tags: algebraic-topology, representation-theory, vector-bundles, k-theory

What is the connection between the K0 group of vector bundles over K(1,G) and the representations of G？If G is a finite group,I guess the Grothendieck ring of its vector bundle is just the ring of its characters with Z-coefficient.Is it right?How to prove it?What about G is not finite group?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: No, things are not quite so simple, but see the Atiyah-Segal completion theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atiyah%E2%80%93Segal_completion_theorem